# VBscript,In a string convert alternate character in upper case

Tags: vbscript, character, alternate

HI I am new in VB Scripting,and stuck in a question and the question is like this.

I have a string (e.g.:- xx xxxxx xxxx xx xxxx xx) in this string i have to convert alternate character in upper case,But should not consider space between the words.

the output of the string should come like this (e.g :- xX xXxXx xXxX xX xXxX xX)

for this i have tried "Mid" and "Ucase" function but in this it was considering space also so my output is not meeting my exception.

Please help me out with this....

Answer (score 1):

Use a RegExp with a pattern looking for an optional space and two symbols and a replace callback function that does the UCase() - as in:

```
Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
      Array("", "") _
    , Array("xx", "xX") _
    , Array("aB cD", "aB cD") _
    , Array("xx xxxxx xxxx xx xxxx xx", "xX xXxXx xXxX xX xXxX xX")_
    , Array(" ab cd", " aB cD") _
  )
  Dim re : Set re = New RegExp
  re.Global = True
  re.Pattern = " ?.."
  Dim rf : Set rf = GetRef("ReRpl")
  Dim aTest
  For Each aTest In aTests
      WScript.Echo "-----", qq(aTest(0))
      Dim sRes : sRes = re.Replace(aTest(0), rf)
      If sRes = aTest(1) Then
         WScript.Echo "   ok", qq(sRes)
      Else
         WScript.Echo "  res", qq(sRes)
         WScript.Echo "  exp", qq(aTest(1))
      End If
  Next

Function ReRpl(sM, nP, sS)
  Dim nL : nL = Len(sM)
  ReRpl = Left(sM, nL - 1) & UCase(Mid(sM, nL))
End Function
```

output:

```
----- ""
   ok ""
----- "xx"
   ok "xX"
----- "aB cD"
   ok "aB cD"
----- "xx xxxxx xxxx xx xxxx xx"
   ok "xX xXxXx xXxX xX xXxX xX"
----- " ab cd"
   ok " aB cD"
```

Please add some more test cases before you go in production; I'm not entirely sure wrt your specs.

**Update:**

To encourage you to work on your specs (add some more samples?), I add two versions of @Ansgar's 'loop over the characters' approach:

```
Function Ucase2ndAW(s)
  Ucase2ndAW = ""
  Dim bUC : bUC = False
  Dim p
  For p = 1 To Len(s)
      Dim c : c = Mid(s, p, 1)
      If " " <> c Then
         If bUC Then c = UCase(c)
         bUC = Not bUC
      End If
      Ucase2ndAW = Ucase2ndAW & c
  Next
End Function
Function Ucase2ndEH(s)
  Ucase2ndEH = ""
  Dim bUC : bUC = False
  Dim p
  For p = 1 To Len(s)
      Dim c : c = Mid(s, p, 1)
      If " " <> c Then
         If bUC Then c = UCase(c)
         bUC = Not bUC
      Else
         bUC = False
      End If
      Ucase2ndEH = Ucase2ndEH & c
  Next
End Function
```

a new test driver:

```
  Dim aTests : aTests = getTests()
  Dim aTest
  Dim re     : Set re = New RegExp
  re.Global = True
  re.Pattern = "( ?.)(.)"
  Dim rf : Set rf = GetRef("ReRpl02")
  For Each aTest In aTests
      WScript.Echo "-----", qq(aTest(0))
      WScript.Echo "  exp", qq(aTest(1))
      WScript.Echo "   AW", qq(Ucase2ndAW(aTest(0)))
      WScript.Echo "   EH", qq(Ucase2ndEH(aTest(0)))
      WScript.Echo "   RE", qq(re.Replace(aTest(0), rf))
  Next
```

and its output:

```
----- ""
  exp ""
   AW ""
   EH ""
   RE ""
----- "xx"
  exp "xX"
   AW "xX"
   EH "xX"
   RE "xX"
----- "aB cD"
  exp "aB cD"
   AW "aB cD"
   EH "aB cD"
   RE "aB cD"
----- "xx xxxxx xxxx xx xxxx xx"
  exp "xX xXxXx xXxX xX xXxX xX"
   AW "xX xXxXx XxXx Xx XxXx Xx"
   EH "xX xXxXx xXxX xX xXxX xX"
   RE "xX xXxXx xXxX xX xXxX xX"
```

Forgot to publish the

```
Function ReRpl02(sM, sG1, sG2, nP, sS)
  ReRpl02 = sG1 & UCase(sG2)
End Function
```

(much easier to let the RegExp engine do the splitting of the match)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this:

```
s1 = "xx xxxxx xxxx xx xxxx xx"
s2 = ""

makeUpperCase = False
For i = 1 To Len(s1)
  c = Mid(s1, i, 1)
  If c = " " Then makeUpperCase = False
  If makeUpperCase Then c = UCase(c)
  s2 = s2 & c
  If c <> " " Then makeUpperCase = Not makeUpperCase
Next

WScript.Echo s2
```

Additional checks are required if you have to deal with non-letter characters as well.

Comment: This does not produce the desired result (see update in my answer).

Comment: All the camel-cased Xs got me confused. Should be fixed now.